# How to style html elements according to ajax response

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, laravel

I have ajax form with change password functionality. The functionality works fine. I show a small notification in the page when the password changing is success with `span` element. I want to show different styling when the response message changes. It shows the same styling for both success and failure response.

```
var dataString = 'old_pass='  +old_pass+ '&new_pass='  +new_pass+ '&re_pass='  +re_pass; 

     $.ajax({

      type : "post",
      url : 'change_password',
      data : dataString,
      headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
      cache : false,
      success : function(data){

         $('#password_notify').addClass('password-success').text(data.msg).fadeOut(2000);
         $('#change_pass_form').find('input:password').val('');

},
       error : function(data){
         alert(data.msg);
}

});
```

Here is my controller code

if (\Hash::check($pass_data['current_pass'],\Auth::user()->password )) 
   {

```
$user = new User();
    if($user->where('id',\Auth::user()->id)->update(['password'=>$pass_data['new_pass']])){
      return response()->json(['msg'=>'Password Changed']);
    }
     }

    else{
       return response()->json(['msg'=>'Wrong Password']);
        }
```

What i want to do is when the response message contains **Wrong Password**. I want to add a different class in ajax notification and if the response message is **Password Changed**. I should add `password-success` class to it

Comment: For best practice, you should return an instance of a [Response](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses) from you Lrvl controller. That way you can set the [HTTP Response code](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) along with your response message and this way you can [map the response code](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) (go here to the statusCode) to determine which state you are handling.

Answer (score 2):

Balancing the logic on both the front and back end requires duplicating effort. Instead, why not just return a view from the backend and just use `.replace()` or nest it and use `.html()`

```
$succes = $user->where('id',\Auth::user()->id)->update(['password'=>$pass_data['new_pass']]);
return response()->json([
    'html' => view()->make('auth.password.partials.response', [
        'success' => $success
    ])->
]);
```

Then you can make the vie at `auth/password/partials/response`. Inside of it, build out your HTML:

```
<div id="password-nofify" class="{{ isset($success) ? 'password-success' : 'password-error' }}">
    @trans('auth.password.'. isset($success) ? 'success' : 'failure')
</div>
```

And then create a `lang` file called `auth` if it doesn't exist. Then add an multidimensional array like this:

```
//resources/lang/en/auth
return [
    'password' => [
        'success' => 'Password Changed',
        'failure' => 'Wrong Password
    ]
]
```

Finally, in your `JavaScript` response. just replace the element:

```
$('#password_notify').replace(data.html).fadeOut(2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check value of `data` in ajax success function and then based on that add different css class.

```
<style>
.password-success
{
    background-color:green
}
.password-error
{
    background-color:red
}
</style>

if(data.msg=="Password Changed")
{
    $('#password_notify').addClass('password-success').text(data.msg).fadeOut(2000);
}
else
{
    $('#password_notify').addClass('password-error').text(data.msg).fadeOut(2000);
}
```

Comment: yes i can do that. Is there anyother proper way to do this or this is the only way to do this ?

Comment: might be other ways, but this is simplest

Answer (score 0):

Return either Success true/false like this:

```
if($user->where('id',\Auth::user()->id)->update(['password'=>$pass_data['new_pass']])){
  return response()->json(['success'=>true, 'msg'=>'Password Changed']);
}
 }

else{
   return response()->json(['success'=>false, 'msg'=>'Wrong Password']);
    }
```

then use data.success to decide which css class to use like this:

```
if(data.success == true){
   $('#password_notify').addClass('password-success').text(data.msg).fadeOut(2000);
}
else{
   $('#password_notify').addClass('password-failed').text(data.msg).fadeOut(2000);
}
```

or return the name of class like this:

```
if($user->where('id',\Auth::user()->id)->update(['password'=>$pass_data['new_pass']])){
  return response()->json(['cssclass'=>'password-success', 'msg'=>'Password Changed']);
}
 }

else{
   return response()->json(['cssclass'=>'password-failed', 'msg'=>'Wrong Password']);
    }
```

and use it in one line like this:

```
$('#password_notify').addClass(data.cssclass).text(data.msg).fadeOut(2000);
```